# How to pass string array using parcelable in android

Tags: android, parcelable

I need to pass a string array or an arraylist to another Activity by using parcelable.
I am able to pass a string or an integer value by using parcelable.

I need some help, if possible.

Here follows my code.

MainActivity

```
    EditText mEtSName;
    EditText mEtSAge;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting a reference to EditText et_sname of the layout activity_main
        mEtSName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_sname);

        // Getting a reference to EditText et_sage of the layout activity_main
        mEtSAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_sage);

      final String[] j={"Hello1","Hello2"};

        // Setting onClick event listener for the "OK" button
        mBtnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Creating an instance of Student class with user input data
                Student student = new Student(mEtSName.getText().toString(),
                Integer.parseInt(mEtSAge.getText().toString()),
                j);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StudentViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("student",student);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my Parcelable Class,

```
    String mSName;
    int mSAge;
    String[] a;

    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(mSName);
        dest.writeInt(mSAge);
        for( int i=0; i<a.length; i++ ){
            dest.writeString(a[i]);
        }
    }

    public Student(String sName, int sAge, String[] s){
        this.mSName = sName;
        this.mSAge = sAge;
        this.a = s;
    }

    private Student(Parcel in){
        this.mSName = in.readString();
        this.mSAge = in.readInt();

        int size = in.readInt();
        a = new String[size];
        for( int i=0; i<size; i++ ){
          this.a[i] = in.readString();
        }
       }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public Student createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Student(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Student[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Student[size];
        }
    };
}
```

May I know what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

U may miss to pass the `length` of `a`, so add like this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(mSName);
        dest.writeInt(mSAge);
        dest.writeInt(a.length);
        for( int i=0; i<a.length; i++ ){
            dest.writeString(a[i]);
        }
    }
```

Or use `writeArray` & `readArray` like this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(mSName);
    dest.writeInt(mSAge);
    dest.writeArray(a);
}

private Student(Parcel in){
    this.mSName = in.readString();
    this.mSAge = in.readInt();

    Object[] objects = in.readArray(null);
    a = new String[objects.length];
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      this.a[i] = objects[i];
    }
   }
```

For `list`, try to use `writeList` & `readList` like this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(mSName);
    dest.writeInt(mSAge);
    dest.writeList(mLists);
}

private Student(Parcel in){
    this.mSName = in.readString();
    this.mSAge = in.readInt();

    this.mLists = new ArrayList<String>();
    in.readList(mLists, null);
   }
```

Hope it helps.